# Quartz JobDetail missing method

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have an application that depends Quartz 1.6.4 version. I upgraded the Quartz to 2.1.6, then comes with compile error:

> **JobDetail** class changed to the interface in new release and does not support **getGroup()** method any more.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
JobDetail jobDetail;
String answer = jobDetail.getKey().getGroup();
```

http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobDetail.html#getKey()

Comment: I changed my code like above but I have new error.
**java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean has interface org.quartz.JobDetail as super class.**
I googled it and spring 3.X is incompatible with quartz 2.X.

Comment: That's too bad; time to upgrade?